# Running cytoscape inside react with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, cytoscape

I have the following simple code:

```
export const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      container: document.getElementById("cy"),
      style: [
        {
          selector: "node",
          style: { content: "data(id)" }
        }
      ],
      elements: [
        { data: { id: "n1" } },
        { data: { id: "n2" } },
        { data: { id: "e1", source: "n1", target: "n2" } }
      ]
    };
    cytoscape(config);
  }, []);
  return <div id="cy" />;
};
```

The page is empty.... https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vo5hv6

How can I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the useRef hook (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) instead of using document.getElementById("cy") directly. It also looks like that you need to set a height for your container element, otherwise it is not visible.

> Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.

```
export default function App() {
  const containerRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      container: containerRef.current,
      style: [
        {
          selector: "node",
          style: { content: "data(id)" },
        },
      ],
      elements: [
        { data: { id: "n1" } },
        { data: { id: "n2" } },
        { data: { id: "e1", source: "n1", target: "n2" } },
      ],
    };

    cytoscape(config);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello cytoscape</h1>
      <div ref={containerRef} style={{ height: "300px" }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import cytoscape from "cytoscape";

export const App = () => {
  const container = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      container: container.current,
      style: [
        {
          selector: "node",
          style: { content: "data(id)" }
        }
      ],
      elements: [
        { data: { id: "n1" } },
        { data: { id: "n2" } },
        { data: { id: "e1", source: "n1", target: "n2" } }
      ]
    };

    cytoscape(config);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello cytoscape</h1>
      <div ref={container} style={{ height: "300px" }} />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. [Reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)